# how to get different parameters in a python function

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to have the different options in a python function or equivalent ie I would like to get the different options in

```
sns.set_style("")
```

how to get the "grid", "dark"...parameters with python instruction ?

It is an example of what I would like. I would like to get all the different options in a API function

Answer (score 1):

[`set_style`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_style.html) has **style** and **rc** parameters and by default is stored as a constant variable `_style_keys = set(rcmod._style_keys)` with all *key-paired* values to display in the UI. This function have some predefined styles ( {**darkgrid, whitegrid, dark, white, ticks**}) that set values to specific options and coloured styles.

```
# // some of "darkgrid" values 
{
 'text.color': '.15',
 'font.family': ['sans-serif'],
 'font.sans-serif': ['Arial',
  'Bitstream Vera Sans',
  'sans-serif'],
 'figure.facecolor': 'white',
 'axes.labelcolor': '.15',
 'axes.edgecolor': 'white',
 'grid.color': 'white'
}
```

To define a custom style, you need to use a dictionary as parameter with each key with pair value, like just to change variables of **_style_keys**, for example `{'axes.labelcolor': '.15', 'axes.edgecolor': '#fff', 'grid.color': '#fff'`}, that means that you can use in *any* order to modify default variables or variables from predefined themes.

```
# custom 
sns.set_style()

# darkgrid
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

# darkgrid modified
sns.set_style("darkgrid", {'axes.labelcolor': '.15',
                           'axes.edgecolor': '#fff',
                           'grid.color': '#fff'})
```